# Build Mobile App (Cordova) using Polymer component with camera functionality

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am making a mobile application using Cordova. It uses polymer 2.0 components to create master/child record in the database.

```
I have to add the file upload and camera feature to the same mobile application. 

in index.html I am using polymer component like this :
        <div style="border: 2px solid green;">
            <crud-expense-mobile employee-id='1234'></crud-expense-mobile>
        </div>
    enter code here

This is my first mobile project. Need guidance from experts
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can look architecture of Apache Cordova. >> [Apache Cordova Architecture](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/#architecture)

You should add which platform want to use. >> [Add platform](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/#add-platforms)

You can look how to add plugins. >> [Add plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/#add-plugins)

How to handle it taked a picture ? >> [Take a picture](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#take-a-picture) or [Take a picture example](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ko/2.0.0/cordova/camera/camera.getPicture.html#full-example)

:)

Comment: I have to call the camera feature from polymer component

Answer (score 0):

```
I am trying to use polymer component : refer 
https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-media/elements/app-media-image-capture

Getting error 
vulcanized-needed-components.html:32222 Uncaught (in promise) Error: ImageCapture instance not ready.
    at HTMLElement.takePhoto (vulcanized-needed-components.html:32222)
    at HTMLElement._addExpenses (crud-expense-mobile.html:232)
    at HTMLElement.handler (vulcanized-needed-components.html:2096)
```